# 'cordova platform add ios' returns 'Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@^6.1.0'

Tags: cordova

Trying to follow the `Create Your First Cordova App` instructions at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/, when trying to add any platform, I get an error. I'm on a Mac, used brew to install node/npm. Node is version 15.1.0, npm is version 7.0.9.

```
$ cordova platform add ios
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^6.1.0
Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@^6.1.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
CordovaError: CordovaError: Could not determine package name from output:
added 87 packages, and audited 87 packages in 2s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: does it happen if you do cordova platform add ios@latest ?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I didn't find a solution and ended up going with Capacitor, which I've had no issues with.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
npm i -g cordova
```

and then

```
cordova platform add ios@latest
```